# Matplotlib figsize specification ignored if in same cell as %matplotlib inline magic

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've always set up my Jupyter notebooks with some boilerplate to load matplotlib and modify the default figure size (amongst other things - the example here is a minimal criminal). I updated anaconda recently and my configuration changes no longer seem to work correctly. I've figured out a workaround but wonder if anyone has an explanation.

Here is how I've always done this (in a single cell):

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
```

As the following figure shows (relative to the subsequent figure), this is not having an effect:

[image]

If I put the `%matplotlib inline` magic in a separate cell, then this problem goes away:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have a *lot* of notebooks with this problem. Is there a way to fix this? Why did the behavior change?

Here is the version info:

```
Software   Version
Python     3.6.4-64bit
IPython    6.2.1
jupyter    1.0.0
matplotlib 2.2.2
```

`conda list --revisions` reports the following as the last updates, if I understand this correctly:

```
 matplotlib  {2.1.0 -> 2.2.2}
 ipython  {6.1.0 -> 6.2.1}
 jupyter_client  {5.1.0 -> 5.2.3}
 jupyter_core  {4.3.0 -> 4.4.0}
```

Comment: I updated matplotlib to 2.2.2. I was using > 2 before but am not certain of the precise version. IPython is 6.2.1, which was probably also updated. The "old" environment was built last November so it was not super out-of-date by any means.

Comment: It can't be matplotlib(alone) , because I tested with 2.2.2 and it works fine, using IPython 5.3 and Jupyter 4.4.1 (the latter are rather old).

Comment: I have the same issue. I just updated to jupyter 5.4.1

Comment: This is still an open issue with IPython/Juypter, see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3385  and  https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11098

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is not longer reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

```
%matplotlib inline
```

It is a line-oriented magic function. Basically, your code is perfect but there is a problem in your code in terms of sequencing.

In this piece of your code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
```

Here you call  "%matplotlib inline"  first before importing matplotlib library.

And in the second case you do the same thing but this time you put "%matplotlib inline" in a different cell and it works. Because in google colab/ jupyter notebook each cell is independent.

Apart from that when you enable the "inline" matplotlib backend, the output of the plotting command is written in the frontend. It means the graph or plot will be displayed below the cell.

That's why you get different outputs in both the case.